# Intent putExtra position of ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have an ArrayList of HashMaps that I am trying to put in an Intent for a detail ListView. I have successfully retrieved the ArrayList in the ListView, but I am stuck on getting the correct position for the ArrayList.

```
// declarations 
JSONArray comments_data = null; 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> comments_list; 


// storing the values 

for (int z=0; z < comments_data.length(); z++)
{
    JSONObject cd = (JSONObject)comments_data.get(z); 
    String commentText = cd.getString("text"); 
    String username = cd.getJSONObject("from").getString("username");

    HashMap<String, String> comments_hash = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

    comments_hash.put("text", commentText); 
    comments_hash.put("from.username", username);

    comments_list.add(comments_hash);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(); 
    i.putExtra("comments_list", comments_list); // HERE IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE ISSUE. I have tried comments_list.get(pos), but it crashes. The current one stores all of the values instead of getting only the values associated with the item that was clicked.

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: You can't just put in extras, there are limitations. For this, it looks like you will likely need to make a parcelable class that contains your hashmap and then pass that using putParcelableArrayListExtra

Comment: @zgc7009 Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Android only really supports passing primitives and a few complex data types. They don't like passing items of bulk (which an ArrayList of HashMaps qualifies as). You need to create a class, something like MyHashMap, that extends Parcelable so that you can parcel your HashMaps into compressed data that your application is happy to pass in a bundle. After setting your variable ArrayList<MyHashMaps> comments_list, you could then put it in your bundle by doing something like putParcelableArrayListExtra("comments_list", comments_list;